# actionscript 2 go to another screen after variable = 10

Tags: actionscript, actionscript-2

I'm making a game where i have a character moving through a maze collecting coins. Once I have collected 10 coins i want my game to automatically go to the end keyframe. The variable Coincounter keeps a record of the number of coins the user has collected so far. So far i have this code to make my game do that....

```
if (_root.Coincounter == 10) {   
trace("got to ten" +_root.Coincounter);  
gotoAndStop(4) ;   
}
```

The code is inside an onClipEvent - either keyDown or enterFrame, i can put it in either of them. The trace works fine so it's my gotoAndStop code that doesn't work - i'm not sure why. Thanks for the help.

Comment: if your clip is in the root try `_parent.gotoAndStop(4);` or `_root.gotoAndStop(4)`: because you have the condition in the onClipEvent gotoAndStop is implicitly this.gotoAndStop and this will point to the clip itself, so you want to go higher in the display hierarchy to the correct clip/timeline

Comment: thanks heaps, i used the _parent.gotoAndStop(4); and that works now :)

Comment: Answers should not be in comments.  This question still looks like its unanswered.